# Message for user before certain date

Tags: php

I need to post a message fro users that have their subscription started before, say Feb 10. I can get their subscription date from db in datatime format. How do I compare the values?

```
$subscr = '2011-05-23 05:17:05';
$cutoff = '2011-02-10';
```

Comment: In PHP `strtotime()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and in MySQL `DATE('2011-05-23 05:17:05')`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL?  Use the date function, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(subscr) > '2011-02-10';
```